# Next13 Property 'query' does not exist on type 'AppRouterInstance'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Property 'query' does not exist on type 'AppRouterInstance'in Nextjs

I am trying to get the items from my json file that match the id of the page in Next13's app directory and am getting Property 'query' does not exist on type 'AppRouterInstance'.

This is the line that is returning the error "const { query } = router;"

and my folder is app/projects/[id]/page.tsx

````
'use client';

import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import data from '../../../data.json'; // Import the data.json file directly
import React from 'react'; // Add this line to import the React object




export default function Work() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { query } = router;
    const id = query?.id;
  
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(data.portfolioData);
    }, []);
  
    const item = data.portfolioData.find((item) => item.id.toString() === id);
  
    if (!item) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }
  
  return (
    <main className="min-h-screen bg-secondary">
      <section>
        <div
          style={{
            backgroundImage: `url("/images/text-bg.png")`,
            backgroundSize: 'cover',
            backgroundPosition: 'center',
            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
          }}
        ></div>
      </section>
      <div className="xl:container mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 xl:px-0">
        <h1 className="mt-12 text-3xl font-bold font-termina text-primary mb-6 text-center sm:text-left">
          <span className="font-light">MY</span> <br></br>DESIGNS
        </h1>

        <div className="bg-accent p-4 card">
          {/* Loop through data.portfolioData */}
          <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-3 2xl:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
            {data.portfolioData.map((item) => (
              <div key={item.id} className="rounded-lg w-auto bg-accent relative transform hover:scale-105 hover:rotate-1 transition-all duration-500 shadow-2xl">
                <img className="rounded-lg" src={item.thumbnail} alt={item.title} />
                <div className="rounded-lg absolute inset-0 flex flex-col items-center justify-center opacity-0 hover:opacity-100 transition-opacity duration-500 bg-black bg-opacity-70">
                  <h3 className="text-md font-termina font-semibold text-white">{item.title}</h3>
               
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

```
````

Answer (score 0):

`searchParams` are passed to each components in nextjs13

```
export default function Work(props) {
    console.log(props)
}
```

you will have this on console

```
 // query will be in searchParams
 { params: {}, searchParams: {} }
```